# Nginx: rewrite for subdomain to folder AND files inside it

Tags: php, nginx, subdomain, rules

I have nginx rewrite rule - it redirects all subdomain requests from sub to folder:

```
server {
listen      x.x.x.x:80;
server_name domain *.domain;

root /home/admin/web/domain/public_html/subs/$subdomain;    # here is IF for subdomains
set $subdomain "";
if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.domain$) {
    set $subdomain $1;
}
if ($host ~* ^www.domain$) {
    set $subdomain "";
}


index       index.php;


location / {    # here is rules for ROOT domain

root        /home/admin/web/domain/public_html;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }
```

........

It work well, but i have one problem.

And in domain and subdomains i have a same php-script that gets data from txt file, like this:

```
file(key.txt);
```

My php-fpm module, i think, doesn't know about nginx rules and gets data in SUB from ROOT domain - it's wrong. 
Please help me to add nginx exceptions or add rule to get txt's data in SUB from SUBs. Not_from_root_domain. Thanks.

Comment: `rewrite $request_uri $subdomain.$request_uri;`         doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You should add additional location to process php files. To simplify rules I moved root directory to `/tmp/subs/root` subdir.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.test *.domain.test;

    set $subdomain "root";
    if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.domain.test$) {
        set $subdomain $1;
    }
    if ($host ~* ^www.domain.test$) {
        set $subdomain "root";
    }

    root /tmp/subs/$subdomain;

    location / {
        index    index.php;

         if (!-e $request_filename) {
             rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
             break;
         }
    }

    location ~ /(.+\.php) {
        index index.php;

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

dir structure:

```
/tmp/subs/root/index.php
/tmp/subs/d1/index.php
/tmp/subs/d2/index.php
/tmp/subs/d2/key.txt
```

/tmp/subs/d2/index.php:

```
<?php
    $file = file('key.txt');
    print_r($file);
```

/tmp/subs/d2/key.txt

```
hello there
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not work for me. According your solution i've moved all files to `/tmp/subs/` and now server returns `File not found.` Here is fixed config for domain, can you see it? https://pastebin.com/9s40VDh3  . i'm also added it to first post

Comment: @BenjaminColeman It seems somewhere in configs you add new location rules which break example above. To find issue just left main rules in the config and then add one by one new location rules.

Comment: Works ok. Thank you very much